# Fail to get secret from Azure Key Vault using user-assigned identity

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-authentication, azure-managed-identity

I have msi added to VMSS, by checking ComputerResourceGroupInfo.json in ElasticAPV2.xts, I have:

```
"ManagedServiceIdentityConfig": {
          "Type": "SystemAssigned, UserAssigned",
          "**UserAssignedIdentities**": [
            "/subscriptions/1234567890qwer/resourceGroups/my-rg/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/my-msi"
          ],
          "ServicePrincipalForSystemAssignedIdentity": "...",
          "ScaleSetIdentity": {
            "principalId": "...",
            "tenantId": "...",
            "type": "SystemAssigned, UserAssigned",
            "**userAssignedIdentities**": {
              "/subscriptions/1234567890qwer/resourceGroups/my-rg/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/my-msi": {
                "principalId": "...",
                "clientId": "..."
              }
```

my-msi is also added to Azure Key Vault access policy with List and Get.

In the VM, Itried to get secret using

```
PS D:\ManagementServiceCommonSetup> $accessToken = (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2018-02-01&resource=https://vault.azure.net' -Method GET -Headers @{Metadata="true"} -UseBasicParsing | ConvertFrom-Json).access_token
PS D:\ManagementServiceCommonSetup> echo $accessToken
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6IkN0ZlFDOExlLThOc0M3b0MyelFrWnBjcmZP...MCQi-bPCJQ
PS D:\ManagementServiceCommonSetup> (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://my-kv.vault.azure.net/certificates/my-cert/587898f2?api-version=2016-10-01 -Method GET -Headers @{Authorization="Bearer $accessToken"}).content
Invoke-WebRequest : {"error":{"code":"Forbidden","message":"Access denied","innererror":{"code":"AccessDenied"}}}
At line:1 char:2
+ (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://my-kv.vault.azure.net/secrets/my-cert/ ...
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebExc
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

My questions:

1. Is this right way to retrieve certificate using access token through
   user-assigned identity?
2. Why the access got denied? My understanding is Access control (IAM) is not need here since I have add msi to access policies.

**Update**:

For user assigned identity, need to specify object id or client id.

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2018-02-01&resource=https://vault.azure.net&object_id=$($ObjectId)" -Method GET -Headers @{Metadata="true"}
```

Answer (score 2):

> 1.Is this right way to retrieve certificate using access token through user-assigned identity?

No, the Uri you used is to [get secret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/getsecret/getsecret), if you want to get a certificate, it should be

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://my-kv.vault.azure.net/certificates/my-cert/587898f2?api-version=2016-10-01 -Method GET -Headers @{Authorization="Bearer $accessToken"}
```

Reference :  [Get Certificate - Get Certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/getcertificate/getcertificate)

> 2.Why the access got denied? My understanding is Access control (IAM) is not need here since I have add msi to access policies.

Your understanding is right. Check it in the `Access policies` again, make sure you have given the `Certificate permissions` (you can also try `Select all`, it is convenient).

[image]

**Update:**

I test it in a windows vm, in the vmss, the logic should be the same, the [doc of VM and VMSS to access the keyvault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/tutorial-windows-vm-access-nonaad) is together.

And if I test with a `system-assigned identity`, it works fine. If I test it with a `user-assigned managed identity`, I also get the 403 error.

The `user-assigned managed identity` is a **Preview** feature, I am not sure if it support to access keyvault, the doc is just for `system-assigned identity`. So I recommend you to use `system-assigned identity` to access keyvault, you could have a try.

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2018-02-01&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fvault.azure.net' -Method GET -Headers @{Metadata="true"} -UseBasicParsing
$content = $response.Content | ConvertFrom-Json 
$KeyVaultToken = $content.access_token 
(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://<keyvault-name>.vault.azure.net/certificates/<{certificate-name}>/<certificate-version>?api-version=2016-10-01 -Method GET -Headers @{Authorization="Bearer $KeyVaultToken"} -UseBasicParsing).content
```

**system-assigned identity**:

[image]

**user-assigned managed identity**:

[image]

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, I did used https://my-kv.vault.azure.net/certificates/my-cert/587898f2. Still get error (403) Forbidden

Comment: You are right about the preview. I figured out that I need to specify client id or object id of msi.

Answer (score 0):

For user assigned identity, need to specify object id or client id.

```
 Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2018-02-01&resource=https://vault.azure.net&object_id=$($ObjectId)" -Method GET -Headers @{Metadata="true"}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Daolin, I tested the same scenario of requesting for an Access Token from AAD using the UserManagedIdentity.

The following cmd worked for me:

```
$response1 = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2018-02-01&resource=https://management.azure.com/&object_id=xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx" -UseBasicParsing -Method GET -Headers @{Metadata="true"}
```

Now, object is the PrincipalID/ObjectID. The ClientID didnt work for me. FOr my case I am using an Azure VM with both SystemManagedIdentity and UserManagedIdentity both enabled. Hence, when I request for an Access Token using the clientID as the query parameter it issues me an access token with the objectID of the System Managed Identity in it.